# Retrieving secrets from AWS with C# without storing access credentials in code base

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, identity, aws-secrets-manager

I want to store sensitive data in my .Net Core C# app in AWS secret manager. I have created my secret in the portal but when I try to access it with the following code:

```
var config = new AmazonSecretsManagerConfig
{
    ProxyHost = "MyProxyHost",
    ProxyPort = 8080,
    ProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    MaxErrorRetry = 1,
    RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.MyRegion,
};

var client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(config);
```

I then get this message when trying to use the secret manager client:

> Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata
> Service

This is unsurprising as I haven't given any information that indicates I should be able to access secrets manager. I can gain access with the following code:

```
var config = new AmazonSecretsManagerConfig
{
    ProxyHost = "MyProxyHost",
    ProxyPort = 8080,
    ProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    MaxErrorRetry = 1,
    RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.MyRegion,
};

var client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient("MyAWSAccessKeyId", "MyAWSSecretAccessKey", config);
```

This though means that I have to store my sensitive data in my application, which is what I wanted to avoid in the first place. In Azure, using KeyVault this could be avoided using the right NuGet package and managed identities. I am wondering if there is a similar solution for AWS for both applications hosted in AWS and local development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IAM roles

Create an IAM role which has [necessary permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconnect/latest/ug/iam-policy-examples-asm-secrets.html#iam-policy-examples-asm-specific-secrets) and attach the role to your EC2 instance. [AmazonSecretsManagerClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=TSecretsManagerClient.html&tocid=Amazon_SecretsManager_AmazonSecretsManagerClient) will assume this IAM role when code is executed from an EC2 instance.

For local development : You can configure [aws credentials with IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html) so that this role will be assumed when your code is executed from local machine.

Comment: Thanks this was useful, I also found this blog post helpful: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/getting-started-with-the-aws-sdk-in-net-core-part-1